# unordered_map overhead with string as key

Tags: c++, visual-studio, hash, unordered-map, overhead

I'm trying to improve the performance of a program. So I use the default profiling tools provided by Visual Studio.

I have this declaration in my header file:

```
    unordered_map<const char*, datad, hash_func, cmp> arguments;
```

The hash function I use is BKDR hash algorithm and the datad is a simple union:

```
union datad
{
    long long d;
    wchar_t* s;
};
```

So after I analyze the performance, I see that we have a lot of CPU overhead on functions related to that unordered_map:
[image: Click the image for a more clear view]

What seems to be the problem? Can you suggest any improvements I can do to reduce the overhead of the map?

p.s: My usage type is simply building the map, accessing the values by key and also iterating through them

Comment: How large do you expect the map to grow?

Comment: I have a limited set of possible keys (about 300) and the map does not grow more than 10 pairs

Comment: And how many times do you perform a lookup?

Comment: A lot. Like saying 300 times in each map...

Comment: There's not nearly enough information here for anyone to know where your performance problems are.  Profiling tools generally show you a call graph and how costly each call is though, so the only advice I can give you is to look through it and see where in your code you're doing more map operations than you need.

Comment: What about using another data structure?

Comment: Who knows.  My point is that there's not enough information in your question for anyone to tell you what your bottleneck is.

Comment: @MoeKav Are you running a "debug" or unoptimized version of your program?  If so, then please run a release / optimized version.   It is practically a prerequisite when asking performance questions to post your build settings.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie nope. Full optimization (-Ox)

Comment: Since the top performance hit here is in the `[]` lookup with the map, show use the code where you're using that to access your map.  You seem to be adding lots of things into the map.  The hash function may also be helpful.

Comment: @MoeKav -- *A lot. Like saying 300 times in each map..* -- Looking up a value in a hash table 300 times is not a lot, and I would say, it is practically nothing.  If you said 30,000 or 300,000 times, then that may make a difference.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yeah but the map is one of the arguments of a class I build 1milion times/sec. I mean one instance of that map is being accessed 300 times. But there are a LOT of maps I use and free the memory after my usage

Comment: @MoeKav -- Then you need to provide a [mcve].  At least one where all that is required is to wrap a `for` loop around it to see how it performs.

Comment: If the hash function you're using isn't returning good hashes or is taking a long time to return them, that'd lower performance. Have you checked the uniformity of your hash function for the data you're using it for? Or looked into the time it takes to generate its values for the data? You can check the `load_factor` and see how high it is to get some insight. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function#Hash_function_algorithms . I suppose if what `s` is pointing to is say a longer string, that could also be problematic.